# How to extract meminfo and cpuinfo of android App Programatically?

Tags: android

I analyze the memory and CPU utilization of my app from the terminal using the below commands

```
 adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
 adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.company.packageName
```

The above approach is manual and would like to extract the data programmatically within my App. I assume android exposes SDK to fetch these values. Can you please suggest the way forward?